# How to display attributes from an object using my_controller in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, view, controller

I want to be able to display attributes from a table anywhere in my application and have them be edited by the user.  This means the data will come from a row in a database.  Each column has a default value which can be changed by the user if they so choose.

The table columns may look like this:

| id | admin_id | practitioner | practitioners | student | students | and so on ...

Here is my model:

```
class Lang_trans_model extends CI_Model {

public function get_lang_trans($admin_id){
    $this->db->where('admin_id', $admin_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('lang_trans');
    return $query->row();
    }
```

Here is my MY_Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {


public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('key_items_model');
    $this->load->model('lang_trans_model');

    foreach ($this->key_items_model->get_key_items() as $result){
        $this->label[$result->key] = $result->value;
    }

    //$admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
    $admin_id = 3;

    $lang = $this->lang_trans_model->get_lang_trans($admin_id);
    //not sure what should go here????
    //I want to be able to use $lang->practitioner; to be able to have practitioner, or the edited attribute to show on the page

var_dump($lang);
// produces the following:
//object(stdClass)[26]
//public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
//public 'admin_id' => string '3' (length=1)
//public 'practitioner' => string 'blah' (length=4)
//public 'practitioners' => string 'blahplural' (length=10)
```

How do I finish the MY_Controller to be able to use these data fields anywhere in my application?

I do not mind using object oriented syntax or array syntax.  Whichever is easier.  I just can not figure out how to display the fields without using a foreach statement in every view.  I want to call the data with the $lang->practitioner; format in the view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assign result to variable i.e `$lang_trans_key_items = $this->key_items_model->get_key_items()`. `var_dump($lang_trans_key_items);exit;` to see what have you got there and in what form.

Comment: What is dump of `$lang`? Edit it in question but format it in tags, please.

Comment: There is no teacher field.

Comment: And what you get on `$lang->practitioner`? That should be correct for use.

Comment: If I were to echo $lang->practitioner from the controller, it works, but I want to echo it from various views.  When I type <?php echo $lang->practitioner; ?> from a view, I get the following errors: 1. Severity: Notice, Message: Undefined variable: lang, and 2. Trying to get property of non-object.  This must have something to do with passing the $lang variable to the views?

Comment: Are you extending MY_Controller or use it to load view file?

Comment: This is at the top of my practitioners controller: ----- class Practitioners extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model("admin/Practitioners_model");
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare parent class properties. Than call it from child class:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $lang;//parent variable declared

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('key_items_model');
        $this->load->model('lang_trans_model');

        foreach ($this->key_items_model->get_key_items() as $result) {
            $this->label[$result->key] = $result->value;
        }

        //$admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
        $admin_id = 3;

        //dedicating value to variable
        $this->lang = $this->lang_trans_model->get_lang_trans($admin_id);
    }
}
```

Child controller:

```
class Practitioners extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // no need to call model if it is called in parent controller
    }

    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->lang);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much.  You are a time saver.  Now, all I have to do is provide the following in a view (html): <?php echo $this->langtrans->practitioner; ?> where practitioner is the attribute to be displayed.

Comment: I had to change the variable $lang to $langtrans because it conflicted with an internal codeigniter variable defined in the CI_Loader file.

Comment: Yes. You have to initialize variable in parent controller than use it in child controller. In my own projects I have one "global" array variable that I call `$data`, than in child controller everything that need to go output is assigned to. For example `$this->data['title'] = $this->Common_m->get_title(); $this->load->view('specific_view', $this->data)`.